# How to modify the email template for order confirmation of tx:cart in TYPO3 10

Tags: typo3, fluid

I wonder where to find the Fluid-template for the order confirmation in tx:cart. In the [manual](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/cart/stable/AdministratorManual/Configuration/Order/Mail/Index.html) I found only the configuration options.

[image: email template tx:cart]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Fluid-based template paths can be configured via

```php
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['MAIL']['layoutRootPaths']
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['MAIL']['partialRootPaths']
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['MAIL']['templateRootPaths']
```

where TYPO3 reserves all array keys below 100 for internal purposes.

If you want to provide custom templates or layouts, set this in your LocalConfiguration.php / AdditionalConfiguration.php file:

```php
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['MAIL']['templateRootPaths'][700] = 'EXT:my_site_extension/Resources/Private/Templates/Email';
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['MAIL']['layoutRootPaths'][700] = 'EXT:my_site_extension/Resources/Private/Layouts';
```

If you want to use the existing templates as a basis for your own templates, you find the original templates in `EXT:core/Resources/Private/`.